# How to add a custom link to header but not in the top links

Tags: module, layout, header, link, magento-1.9.3.3

In my custom module, I want to add a custom link in the header, but not within the top links.
I can't edit the header.phtml. I prefer add link through layout

http://i.prntscr.com/971IF0J_SGm72aCvgkq1GQ.png

Answer (score 0):

The header block is not of type `text_list` which would automatically echo all of it's child blocks, therefor you have to manually specify each block that you want to output. In other words, you have to change the `header.phtml` template

Answer (score 0):

You should add something in `header.phtml` because he can't render automatically all the blocks in content, but you can do it properly like this:

**app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml**

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="core/template" name="new.link" template="page/html/header/link.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

**app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/html/header/link.phtml**

```
<a href="#">My new link</a>
```

**app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/html/header.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('new.link') ?>
```